# How to send message during video call on twilio

Tags: twilio

In addLive API we can send a message while video calling 
http://api.addlive.com/beta/apidocs/ADL.AddLiveService.html#sendMessage

Now i want to replace my addlive with twilio and i am able to video call but i could not find how can i sent a message (chatting) to client

```
var videoClient = new Twilio.Video.Client(twilioToken);


videoClient.connect({ to: roomName }).then(roomJoined, function (error) {
  $scope.isError = true;
  console.log('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
  console.log(error)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio Video doesn't directly support chatting. However, you could use [Twilio's Programmable Chat API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat) to implement chat alongside your Video conversations. Take a look at the [Chat documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/chat-fundamentals) and see if that might help.